# Expresso Store : Add customer member fields to checkout process

Tags: expresso-store, members, checkout, register

Is it possible to have custom member fields added to the checkout process so when the customer is registered during checkout the custom member fields are saved?

I've tried adding the fields to my form (I copied the HTML from the /members/register page), but the values I enter are not saved during registration.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sure is. You just need to make sure you've mapped them to Store's order/custom order fields.

Create your custom member fields in Members > Member Fields.

Then, in Store > Settings > Order fields make sure the fields are mapped up to the member fields. If they are custom fields then use order_custom1-9. The right hand column is where you select which Member field (or Zoo Visitor field if you're using that addon) to map to.

Then include the appropriate fields in the Store checkout form: {order_custom1} etc. Those will be saved upon submission and mapped to the member fields.

Comment: Good stuff. Many thanks Ian. Nice and simple solution.