# Expresso Store: pseudo-subscriptions

Tags: expresso-store, members, freemember

With Exp-resso Store, can I update a custom member field on checkout?

I'm working on an site for an academic society and I'm hoping to use Store and Freemember to manage membership dues. Suppose I set up a custom member field called Paid Through Date (YYYY-MM-DD). Assuming I require customer registration, can I sell a "2 year subscription" product and have that Paid Through Date get calculated and updated? Would I just do the date calculations in PHP and put submit a hidden input form input on checkout? Is `<input type="hidden">` even secure for POSTed data? If not, is there another way to track this "Paid Through" info for each member?

[Adrian implies here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9382/expresso-store-how-to-use-the-checkout-tag-without-any-items-in-the-cart/9418#9418) that custom member fields (not just the mapped name/email/address info) *can* be updated at checkout when a product is purchased.

Comment: Just located [this question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7772/expresso-store-add-customer-member-fields-to-checkout-process/8775#8775), which implies this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many custom fields you want to per item you sell or you can add upto 9 custom order fields per order which can then in turn be mapped to custom member fields. There is nothing in Store that would allow you to use tho result of the custom field to prevent user access to subscription items before/after the date that you created.

Yes you would need to either use PHP or a plugin to get the current date and calculate the date in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm not really expecting to cut access off to anything with that field -- just want to output a list for the admins so they can see if people are past due.